# $\Pr(A \cap B \cap C)=\Pr(A\cap B \cap D)$ implies $\Pr(A \cap B \cap C^c)=\Pr(A\cap B \cap D^c)$?

Tags: probability

Consider four events $A,B,C,D$. Assume that
$$
\Pr(A \cap B \cap C)=\Pr(A\cap B \cap D)
$$

Is it true that
$$
\Pr(A \cap B \cap C^c)=\Pr(A\cap B \cap D^c)
$$
where $C^c$ and $D^c$ are the complements of $C$ and $D$, respectively?

Comment: The "$A\cap B$" part is irrelevant, because all it accomplishes is to limit your sample space to $A\cap B.$  This reduces the question to asking whether $\Pr(C)=\Pr(D)$ implies $\Pr(C^c)=\Pr(D^c).$  I suspect you can easily answer that.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, just note

\begin{align}
& P(A \cap B) = P(A \cap B \cap C) + P(A \cap B \cap C^c), \\
& P(A \cap B) = P(A \cap B \cap D) + P(A \cap B \cap D^c).
\end{align}

Comment: Yes, and $A\cap B$ does not really seem to matter for the argument, so that we might replace the lhs with 1 and remove $A\cap B$ from the rhs?

Comment: @ChristophHanck In principle, yes (it is just about viewing $A \cap B$ as $\Omega$).  But as a formal proof, we may still need to carry $A \cap B$ over, I think...

Answer (score 6):

The expression can be further simplified by setting $E = A\cap B$. Thus your question becomes:

Does (the premise)

$$P(E\cap D)$$ imply

$$
P(E\cap C^c) = P(E\cap D^c)?
$$

**Proof.** Yes indeed,
$$P(E\cap C^c) = P(E) - P(E\cap C) ,\tag{*}$$

and

$$P(E)-E(E\cap D) = P(E\cap D^c).\tag{**}$$

Using the premise in (*) and equating this with (**), we get the desired equality.